# Python matplotlib scale y based on values from larger dataset

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, colormap

I would like to make a plot with values from a dataset that were subsetted from a larger dataset, and I would like to scale the plotted colours based on where those values are in the larger dataset.

For example if I have df1 (larger dataset) and df2 (smaller dataset), I want to plot a columne from df2 such that the points are coloured with a colormap that ranges from red to green, where the limits are based on the minimum (red) and maximum (green) of the corresponding larger column of df1.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

n = 50
N = n*10
this_mean = 5
group_mean = 3

# column to plot
y = np.random.normal(this_mean, 1, 50)
x = list(range(n))

# From within larger dataset
Y = np.random.normal(group_mean,1,N)
X = list(range(N))
```

Scaling based on the data plotted on that axis is fine:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10,4), sharey=True)

ax[0].scatter(x, y, c=y, cmap=cm.RdYlGn)
ax[1].scatter(X, Y, c=Y, cmap=cm.RdYlGn)
ax[0].set_title('subset')
ax[1].set_title('all')
plt.show()
```

[image]

In this example, what I'd really like is for the colours on the left plot to correspond to those on the right, so we expect to see its minimum values coloured as orange, and most other points as very green.

But when I attempt to scale by the larger data `Y`, there is obviously a size mismatch error :

```
plt.scatter(x, y, c=Y, cmap=cm.RdYlGn)

ValueError: 'c' argument has 500 elements, which is not acceptable for use with 'x' with size 50, 'y' with size 50.
```

I'm not sure how to achieve this. Also the data of `y` are not actually subsetted from `Y` in this example, but they are with my actual dataset. I'm not sure if this is important for the solution though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first plot the complete set and take the colormap and normaliztion from that and apply it to the subset plot.

```
# First plot the complete set
sc = ax[1].scatter(X, Y, c=Y, cmap=cm.RdYlGn)
# Plot the subset with the colormap and normalization
# taken from the complete set
ax[0].scatter(x, y, c=y, cmap=sc.cmap, norm=sc.norm)
```

[image]

More generally, you can also define the colormap and normalization prior to plotting anything and use those for both plots.

```
cmap = cm.RdYlGn
norm = plt.Normalize(Y.min(), Y.max())

#...

ax[0].scatter(x, y, c=y, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
ax[1].scatter(X, Y, c=Y, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
```